# Compilation error while upgrading from Guava 19 to 20

Tags: java, guava, errorprone

Trying to upgrade guava from version 19 to 20 and getting this error:

```
Error:java: cannot access com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue
  class file for com.google.errorprone.annotations.CanIgnoreReturnValue not found
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I don't have any references to errorprone in my project.
Adding dependency to `errorprone` like below doesn't help:

```
        <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
        <artifactId>error_prone_annotations</artifactId>
```

Comment: I presume you are using Java 8. Please confirm?

Comment: Guava 20 already has error_prone_annotations v2.0.12 dependency. The error_prone_annotations v2.0.12 has the CanIgnoreReturnValue annotation class.

Comment: @notionquest yes, build 1.8.0-b132

Comment: "Guava 20 already has error_prone_annotations v2.0.12 dependency" - yes, but it "optional", not sure what it mean

Comment: May be it's issue with too old maven version (3.1.1)

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: I see the same issue when upgrading from Guava 19 -> 21 using Maven 3.3.9.  I needed the dependency noted by @valodzka.

Answer (score 7):

Solved by adding errorprone dependency manually:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
        <artifactId>error_prone_annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
```